# Function Return Issue in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hello Pine Script community,

I'm encountering a puzzling issue in my Pine Script code, and I'm seeking some expertise to help me understand and resolve it. In a simplified version of my indicator, I'm trying to get the `haLow` of the previous candle after a Heikin Ashi color change from red to green. While directly using `haLow` works as expected, when I encapsulate the logic in a function, the returned value seems to be incorrect.

Here's a simplified representation of the problem:

```
//@version=5 indicator("My script", overlay=true)

haTicker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) 
haOpen = request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, open, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) 
haHigh = request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, high, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) 
haLow = request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, low, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on) 
haClose = request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, close, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)

isRed = haOpen > haClose isGreen = haOpen < haClose

haBull = isRed[1] and isGreen haBear = isGreen[1] and isRed

prevLow() =>
    haLow[1]

if haBull
    prevlow = prevLow()
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high+5, text=str.tostring(haLow[1]), color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_center)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high+2, text=str.tostring(prevlow), color=color.rgb(82, 255, 97), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_center)
```

In this script, the label displaying `haLow[1]` is working correctly, but when I use the function `prevLow()`, the displayed value is unexpected.

I've tried various approaches, but I can't seem to identify the root cause. If anyone has insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy in function returns, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you for your time and assistance!